# How to extract a class from column using pandas

Tags: python

[In the last column, I am trying to extract and only display a class. For example, 'truck' or 'car'. Do anyone know how to list them?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igOMn.png)

Comment: `df[df['col_name'].str.contains('truck')]` ?

Comment: It works. Thanks. But how do I list the "first value"? Lets say the value is bike instead of truck and I don't know it

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if `str.contains` your search value

```
df[df['col_name'].str.contains('truck')]
```

Or use a chained `str.get` and get the occurrences

```
df.col1.str.get(0).str.get(0)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col1'] = [[['truck',3, ('a',2)]], [['car', 2, ('b', 2)]]]

    col1
0   [[truck, 3, (a, 2)]]
1   [[car, 2, (b, 2)]]
```

where

```
df.col1.str.get(0).str.get(0)
```

yields

```
0    truck
1      car
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

So you can use `loc`

```
df.loc[df.col1.str.get(0).str.get(0).eq('truck')]

    col1
0   [[truck, 3, (a, 2)]]
```